# Does CClientDC guarantee restoring the DC back to its previous state?

Tags: winapi, mfc, gdi

I am using a `CClientDC` object, which serves as a wrapper for functions `GetDC` and `ReleaseDC`:

- Function `GetDC` is called from inside the `CClientDC` constructor
- Function `ReleaseDC` is called from inside the `CClientDC` destructor

In between, I manipulate the DC (changing pens, brushes, etc).

But I'm pretty sure that the `CClientDC` object does not restore the DC back to its previous state.

This means I have to make sure of it myself. Is that correct?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes. It's unclear what you are trying to accomplish, though (given your question history). Why not simply go by the established rules?

Comment: @IInspectable: I am trying to avoid calling `GetDC`, `ReleaseDC`, `SaveDC` and `RestoreDC` in several `OnPaint` handlers in my code. The `CClientDC` class helps me with the first two. I was hoping that there would be an infrastructure to help me with the others. At the moment, I ended up writing a small `class CAppDC : public CClientDC`.

Comment: You should be using `CPaintDC` in `OnPaint` handlers, not `CClientDC`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open `wingdi.cpp` from the MFC source code and look for the implementation of `CClientDC`:

```
CClientDC::~CClientDC()
{
    ASSERT(m_hDC != NULL);
    ::ReleaseDC(m_hWnd, Detach());
}
```

You see that it only calls [`ReleaseDC`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162920(v=vs.85).aspx), which does *not* restore the DC to its previous state. There is no way for `CClientDC` to know which GDI objects you changed.

If you want to save and restore the DC's state, there are special methods for this: [`CDC::SaveDC`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/715b3334-cb2b-4c9c-8067-02eb7c66c8b2.aspx#cdc__savedc) and [`CDC::RestoreDC`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/715b3334-cb2b-4c9c-8067-02eb7c66c8b2.aspx#cdc__restoredc). These are not called automatically from `CDC` or `CClientDC`—you need manually call them yourself.

Or, you can save and restore each individual GDI object that you modify. When you call [`SelectObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162957(v=vs.85).aspx), the original object is returned. You save this, and restore it as you deselect the object you were using.

Comment: Thanks. 1. "Open `wingdi.cpp` from the MFC source code" - that's exactly what I did (though via step-into from the debugger). And that's why I wrote "I'm pretty sure" (though I guess I could have chosen a better way to put it). 2. "There is no way for `CClientDC` to know which GDI objects you changed." - Yes, that too is obvious to me. I've been wondering why that wrapper class doesn't simply call `SaveDC` and `RestoreDC`. I ended up writing a small `class CAppDC : public CClientDC` to do exactly that. But I am wondering how come this infrastructure isn't already viable.

Comment: @goodvibration: Because the system isn't optimized for the uncommon case. The common case is: The application knows when it needs to restore the initial state, and how. MFC does not. You already know about the `CS_OWNDC` style, so that shouldn't come as a surprise.

Comment: The general philosophy of C++ is that you should not pay for what you do not need. In writing *lots* of Windows code, I have only needed `SaveDC`/`RestoreDC` *once*. So why should the overhead of saving and restoring be forced upon *all* users of a DC? @good

Comment: Also, while it could make sense for `CClientDC::SelectObject()` to remember its first call for each object type and undo only the changed object types in the destructor (to avoid the common mistake of forgetting to do so yourself), but a) IDK if MFC was designed to actually hide work from programmers or just to C++-ize existing work, and b) that would still break with `CS_OWNDC`, [sometimes with hilarious results](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060601-06/?p=31003).

Comment: @andlabs: [CDC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxhhde73.aspx)-derived classes implement `operator HDC()` as well as have a **public** `m_hDC` class member. Both allow sidestepping the `CDC::SelectObject` implementation and call `::SelectObject` directly. At that point it's moot, whether or not the `CDC` implementation tries to restore its initial state, because there is no guarantee that it even can (by monitoring the first `SelectObject` call for each graphics object).